# Gone X days without vs gone X days

Tags: grammar

The sentence "he has gone 4 days without eating any food" seems grammatical. However, "he has gone 4 days eating only vegetables" seems ungrammatical. Can "gone" only be used with without in this context?

Answer (score 2):

Don't let the past tense or altered word order fool you: "go without" is a phrase. The sentence could be reordered as "He has gone without eating any food for four days." But you don't "go eating."

The usage is admittedly confusing because we could also use "go" in a more literal sense along with a measurement of distance, and this could "go" "with" or "without":

> I've gone four miles without seeing a gas station.
> I've gone four miles with my coffee mug on the roof.

Comment: I don't find *go four days eating only...* ungrammatical. Looking at some google book examples, I find *... asked if I could go one hour without sin. And of course, if it was possible to go one hour, then it must be possible to go one day living perfectly, without sin.* That example shows a smooth transition from *go without* to *go living perfectly*.  I don't think there's really a difference between going a physical distance and going through an interval of time. Both *go without*  and *go* followed by a positive condition refer to traversing a time interval.